# What is the most compelling evidence of General Relativity in the presence of matter and energy?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, experimental-physics, observational-astronomy

The most oft-cited [triumphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) of GR are things such as the shifting perihelion of Mercury, gravitational redshift experiments, and gravitational lensing. But, as far as I know, these are only verifications of Einstein's equation in a vacuum: $$R_{\mu\nu}=0.$$
(In fact, I think the former two are predicted in the Schwarzchild metric, the spherical solution to the vacuum equation.)

But what do we have as far as compelling evidence that the Einstein equation is valid in the presence of matter and energy? i.e.
$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu} = 8 \pi G T_{\mu\nu}.$$

Are we simply happy with this because it is the simplest form of an equation in the presence of matter and energy where the left hand side has the same conservation law as the right side (due to the Bianchi identity)? Or are there actual experimental/observational verifications of solutions to this equation where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is not trivial?

EDIT: I just want to be clear. There's a difference between "*in* the presence of matter and energy" and "*near* the presence of matter and energy". People keep on citing verifications of the vacuum field equation $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ that happen to have nonzero curvature because of nearby matter (the Schwarzchild metric is an example of this). The *full* Einstein equation comes to play when $T_{\mu\nu} \ne 0$, and this describes the expression of the metric tensor at the *same* point in the manifold where T is nonzero, not just a nearby point. I'm asking if anybody knows of any tangible verification of a solution to the Einstein equation for a *nonzero* energy-momentum tensor, so that excludes most of the examples people gave. And if there is none, how confident are we to assume the full equation just by symmetry arguments alone? I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10484/2451 and links therein.

Comment: How about precision measurements on pulsars? That's a lot of matter... You can, by the way, easily extend GR. The most straight forward extension is Einstein-Cartan, which allows torsion.

Comment: I don't know the details, but the metric used in GPS calculations might not be a vacuum solution--[this page](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2003-1&amp;page=articlese3.html) seems to say the solution takes into account the actual ellipsoid shape of the planet.

Comment: Specifically, notice the comment "Better models can be found in the literature of geophysics [18, 9Jump To The Next Citation Point, 15]. The next term in the multipole expansion of the earth’s gravity field is about a thousand times smaller than the contribution from J2; although the actual shape of the geoid can differ from Eq. (20View Equation) by as much as 100 meters, the effects of such terms on timing in the GPS are small"

Comment: @CuriousOne: Are you talking about the perihelion precession of binary pulsars as described in the "tests of GR" wiki? Doesn't that suffer from the same problem as the Mercury example I cited? The perihelion precession is something calculated from the Schwarzchild metric, which is a vacuum solution.

Comment: @Qmechanic: that doesn't look very related. All I saw there were people linking verifications of special relativity; the only GR link I saw was the wiki page that has the same problem that I brought up. My question is much more specific.

Comment: @Hypnosifi: I'll have to look at that in more detail, but from the look of it they're just using the Scharzchild metric. The note at the end is just a note on how the geometry of the metric has a slight deviation from spherical symmetry, but it's still talking about geodesics of objects in a vacuum, whose metric is obeyed by $R_{\mu\nu} = 0.$ I'm looking for evidence of solutions directly in the presence of mass/energy (nontrivial $T_{\mu\nu}$).

Comment: @Bridgeburners: Not sure what "problem" you are having here. In absence of matter spacetime is essentially flat except for strong gravitational waves (which we haven't been able to observe directly, yet). In presence of matter the measurements are agreeing nicely with the theory, so far. As for myself, I am pretty sure that we are missing something with GR, there is just not enough data to nail it down.

Comment: @Bridgeburners: I'd guess CuriousOne is referring to gravitational wave radiation from the Hulse-Taylor binary.

Comment: [The Confrontation between General Relativity and Experiment](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377)

Comment: Good question, not a duplicate, and as the OP is right to note all suggestions in the comments are tests *only* of the vacuum field equation.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: there's a lot of vacuum in the universe. If you're going to dismiss any test that takes place where there is more vacuum than matter you'll struggle to find anything to test. The argument that the Hulse-Taylor GR observation only tests a vacuum solution seems mischievous to me.

Comment: @CuriousOne Perhaps there's a confusion here. A solution to the vacuum equation is a solution to the metric at some point in the manifold where the energy-momentum tensor _at that point_ is zero. So the Schwarzchild metric, for example, is a solution to the vacuum equation even though it assumes a mass nearby. The full Einstein equation talks about the metric exactly at a point in the manifold where matter/energy is present. You're confusing "_in_ the presence of mass energy" with "_near_ the presence of mass energy".

Comment: @Bridgeburners: As an experimentalist I am confused about how some people think that they can get a (not-trivial) Schwarzschild metric without borrowing a star's worth of matter. You may want to show me that trick on occasion, otherwise I may just think that you are mostly interested in semantics.

Comment: @Bridgeburners - Do you mean that even when they model the gravitational field of an ellipsoid, they are still treating it as a singularity surrounded by vacuum? Or are they just using a metric that deals with some "exterior" patch, without specifying whether the "interior" consists of a singularity or a continuous distribution? Also, when you ask for solutions "in the presence of matter" are you including predictions about test particle motion in a vacuum region surrounding a finite volume of matter, or do you specifically want predictions *inside* of a matter field?

Comment: In light of @ChrisWhite's comment, I'm voting to leave this open. I am wondering/thinking, though, if it should have been made as a bounty on the previous question to explicitly ask for non-vacuum examples.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, precisely I want predictions of at _least_ the form of the metric, or more, inside the actual presence of matter fields. If you talk about the motion of particles outside of the presence of matter, no matter the shape of the actual nearby matter, they still move according to the connection determined by a metric that solve the vacuum equation. What I'm looking for is evidence of the whole equation, beyond simply the vacuum equation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most compelling evidence of GR in presence of matter is, in my opinion, in neutron stars. These objects have a surface gravity $SG$ that is (geometric units):

$SG_{NS}=GM/c^2 R \simeq 0.1 $

This value is telling us that we can't use Newtonian gravity because we are in the strong field limit. For comparison, the sun has $SG_{SUN}=GM/c^2 R \simeq 10^{-5} $ and we are in the weak field limit.

So inside a Neutron star the usual equations of stellar structure derived from Newton are not accurate. Just for reference, the Newtonian equations are:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
{d\over dr} M(r)=4\pi r^2\rho_M\\
{d\over dr} p(r)=-\frac{M \rho_M}{r^2}\\
p=p(\rho_M)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

in which $M(R)$ is the mass of the star, $R$ the radius of the star, $\rho_{M}$ the mass density, $p(r)$ the pressure. The last equation is the Equation Of State (EOS).

Now, let's go to GR. Let's represent the neutron star as a spherically symmetric (and static) object. (you can study a dynamic star, like I've done in my master's thesis, but the formalism is much more complicated). The metric is:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{
ds^2=-e^{\nu(r)}dt^2+e^{\lambda(r)}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2{\theta}d\phi^2)
}
\end{equation}

Let's assume that the star is composed by a perfect fluid. 
In this case:

\begin{equation}
T^{\mu\nu}=(\epsilon+p)u^{\mu}u^{\nu}+pg^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

in which $\epsilon$ is the energy density. Now solve the Einstein equations. It's rather easy, and you find the TOV equations (Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff) that generalize Newton equations. They are:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{
\begin{cases}
{d\over dr} m(r)=4\pi r^2\epsilon\\
{d\over dr} p(r)=-\frac{(\epsilon+p)(m+4\pi r^3p)}{r(r-2m)}\\
\end{cases}
}
\end{equation}

Of course you have to add an EOS again. You can use a simple polytropic form like $p=\epsilon^{\gamma}$. (actually in real calculations you use tabulated data of the possible internal structure: degenerate gases of neutrons and electrons, quarks, heavy baryons, and so on).

Now it's time to solve numerically. You get for example predictions for mass and radius of a star of given central pressure. These predictions of GR nicely fit the experimental data.

Directly from my thesis, I can show you the (non particularly spectacular) functions $m(r)$ and $p(r)$ inside the star.

[image: mass]

In the horizontal axis you can see the $r$ coordinate in $Km$. In the vertical one the ratio $m(r)/M_{SUN}$. The function m(r) is roughly speaking the mass inside a sphere of radius $r$, so the value $m(R)$ is the mass that you can measure from outside. The radius of the star is determined with the pressure graph:

[image: pressure]

When the pressure goes to zero it means that we have reached the surface of the star. So in this case, the star as a radius of $\simeq 14 Km$ and is mass is $\simeq 1.5 M_{SUN}$. (every star is uniquely identified by his pressure, or equivalently his energy density, at the center of the star).

EDIT:

To be more explicit, here there is a parametric graph of the mass and the radius of the star when we change the central pressure. Every point in the graph is a stable  stellar configuration predicted by GR (the blue line). The yellow and purple line are predictions from some scalar tensor theories of gravity (possible alternative theories to GR).

[image]

For example, an immediate prediction is that the maximum value of the mass for a neutron star is below $2.5 M/M_{SUN}$. (of course the precise value depend on the EOS you use). This is absolutely confirmed by experimental data.

Some references:

-Schutz, A first Course in General Relativity cap.10  (static stars)

-Hartle (1967), Slowly rotating relativistic stars

Comment: Could you add a little something on what kind of experimental evidence there is that these curves are accurate for real astrophysical neutron stars?

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how you got the mass-radius curves by observation? Also, is there a good source in where the TOV equations are derived?

Comment: @Bridgeburners Wikipedia has a [derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation#Derivation_from_General_Relativity). As for getting masses and radii for the same objects -- that has proven rather difficult. There aren't any particularly good datapoints in that parameter space... yet. Also, predictions for such data points are influenced not only by pure GR, but also by your assumed equation of state.

Answer (score 7):

Frame-dragging effects are dependent on the spin of the central object, have been measured by experiments such as Gravity Probe B, and are definitely not dependent on the central metric.

Also, any effects on a galactic scale are best quantified in terms of a continuous matter distribution, since the central black hole is a small fraction of the galaxy's mass.

Also, you have all of the predictions of cosmology, which explicitly invokes a spatially constant matter density.

You also have the prediction for Chandrasekhar-style mass limits for neutron stars and white dwarfs, which have not been contradicted by observation, and are confirmed by the presence of white dwarf and neutron star supernovae.  There would be no theoretical explaination of their utility as standard candles without Einstein's equation in the presence of matter.

Finally, even the predictions of the schwarzschild metric applying to solar system observations is dependent on the equation satisfying Birchoff's theorem.  A different coupling to matter would not have to respect this.

EDIT:

Also, the hulse-taylor binary radiation effect is in no way dependent on either the schwarzschild solution or a matter-free distribution.  It is a test of the gravitational radiation equation, which has a time derivative of the quadrupole moment of the matter source in it.

Answer (score 2):

The field equations of general relativity give rise to a phenomenon called [gravitomagnetism](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2004/19apr_gravitomagnetism/), which is related to "monopole" gravity in the same way that magnetism is related to moving electric charges by special relativity. There is conclusive evidence for gravitomagnetism just in the past five years, weakly from the Gravity Probe B mission, and more convincingly from [lunar laser ranging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment).

Gravity Probe B was a very carefully-designed satellite which tracked the precession of gyroscopes in low earth orbit; GR predicts that the precession is different if the orbit goes to the east, with Earth's rotation, or to the west.  It's profoundly non-Newtonian effect, but required very precise measurement; the final error bar was a little disappointing.

The lunar laser ranging experiment measures the time delay for a laser pulse to return from the retroreflectors left on the moon by Apollo astronauts. It turns out that because the moon and earth are *both* very massive, there are gravitomagnetic effects that change the moon's [libration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration) by roughly ten meters; the position precision on the timing technique is a few centimeters.

John Rennie linked in a comment to [a review by Clifford Will](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377); the [PDG review](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-gravity-tests.pdf) is also useful.

Comment: And there's also GPS, which explicitly models relativistic (special and general) effects.