# Why general relativity test carried out so many times?

Tags: general-relativity

My question is different from this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/testing-general-relativity). Why general relativity test carried out so many times?

In this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) says that it carried so many times.

Comment: The Wikipedia article describes many different ways of testing GR. The reason for that is given in the question you linked. I think you are actually asking the same thing in a different way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/testing-general-relativity)

Answer (score 2):

Physicists realize that regarding GR, it cannot be the whole story about gravity because it fails to yield useful results in the conditions that were present at very early times in the history of the universe. This means that there may be clues as to what lies beyond GR, in the data from more and more precise tests of it. This is why those tests are ongoing.

Comment: Also to be noted is the fact that it fails to reconcile with QM in extreme cases. To find missing elements of the theory (in the hope that it'll work with QM), we conduct tests.

Comment: @user220704, that is what I was alluding to regarding early times in the big bang.